# Contentful export server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, export, contentful

I am trying to export the data from one of my spaces within contentful using the https://github.com/contentful/contentful-export npm package. However when I run my code, following the example on the github page, I get the following error:

```
info Getting content from source space
Server error occured. Waiting for 3208 ms before retrying....
```

Below is my code:

```
var spaceExport = require('contentful-export')
var options = {
  spaceId: '{XXX}',
  managementToken: '{XXX}',
  maxAllowedItems: 100,
  errorLogFile: 'filename',
  saveFile: false
}
spaceExport(options)
.then((output) => {
  console.log('Your space data:', output)
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Oh no! Some errors occurred!', err)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the message the tool will wait for 3208 milliseconds and try again since there was an error while performing a request. This is to avoid breaking an export or import. After retrying few times the tool will eventually fail if it is not able to continue.
However, I think you might be providing a wrong management token in this case.
Can you check your credential and try again.

Best,
Khaled

Comment: I am getting a management token from https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/authentication/ specifically the Getting an OAuth Token section. Is this the correct token?

Comment: Yes it is correct, can you click logout and login again?